# no module found Django model request

Tags: python, django, menu, model, request

My will is to make a select menu with the folowing options:

```
models.py
TITLE_CHOICES = (
    ('MR', 'Mr.'),
    ('MRS', 'Mrs.'),
    ('MS', 'Ms.'),
)
```

and display it on `hello.html`. But I keep getting this error: `ImportError: No module named hello`

The object:
    #continuation of models.py

```
class hello(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=TITLE_CHOICES)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

The request on view.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.template import Context
from testApp.models import hello
from testApp.models.hello import title
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext


def contato(request):
    form = hello()
    return render_to_response(
       'hello.html',
        locals(),
        context_instance=RequestContext(request),
    )

def hello_template(request):
    t = get_template('hello.html')
    html = t.render(Context({'name' : title}))
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

My app in `INSTALLED_APPS` (`setting.py`):

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'testApp',
'hello',
)
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why is it `hello` in your installed apps? I think that might be the problem. `hello` is a class in your `models.py` that belongs to your `testApp`. `testApp` is the only thing you have to include in your `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Also, you should remove from the code this line too: `from testApp.models.hello import title` that's gonna yield an error too because you can't import a field from a class. If you need access to `title` field, you must do it this way:

```
def contato(request):
    form = hello()
    title = form.title
    return render_to_response(
       'hello.html',
        locals(),
        context_instance=RequestContext(request),
    )

def hello_template(request):
    t = get_template('hello.html')
    # see here the initialization and the access to the class field 'title'
    title = hello().title
    html = t.render(Context({'name' : title}))
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

Comment: it stoped giving error when i validate, but when i run the server and try to acess the hello.html it returns a import error on views.py in line : `from testApp.models.hello import title`

Comment: Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value: 
No module named hello

Comment: Remove that line as well. `hello` is a class, not a module, you can't import nothing from it. `title` is a field in the hello class. You don't import it, you import `hello` and access to `title` from the hello class.

Comment: i guess i have to put `title = form.title` in `def hello_template(request):` because it's where title is called

Comment: Despite it works on `def contato(request)` on `def hello_template(request)` form is an undefined variable

Comment: You have to initialize the `form` class first. I'm gonna update the answer with the `hello_template` method

Comment: Sorry, I mean the `hello` class.